# Animate table background on hover - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I'm trying to put an animation on my table..
When the mouse enters the current table, it should turn black.
When the mouse leaves the current table, it should turn white.

This is my code. It works fine untill I add the animation effect (I don't want it to be instant, I want it to fade). Can anyone help me? :)

```
$("table").on('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).animate({
    backgroundColor: "#000000"
    }, 1000);
})
$("table").on('mouseleave',function(){
   $(this).animate({
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
    }, 1000);
});
```

SOLVED
Cannot animate backgroundColor. I downloaded a JS file from Bitstorm (http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/) and it solved my problem! Thanks, Bitstorm

Comment: Enough time hasn't passed between asking and answering, but when it has, you should move your solution into an answer and give more details.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else who may view this, it is easily solvable with some CSS.

```
table {
  transition: 1s;
  background-color: #000;
}
table:hover {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Then the JS is not needed at all. But you still have the fade when mousing over the table.

FYI, `.animate()` deals with motion, which is why it was not working.